# Error in installing line-in package: NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js, npm, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am trying to use the `line-in` package to stream the input audio data as output. While installing the package, I get the error stating `node-gyp` rebuild command failed.

I am using NodeJS, and I really don't know why node-gyp is trying to access my `python.exe` file. Can anybody help me to sort this problem out?

````
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\NikhileshSubramanian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd F:\Topgear\SpeechToText\node_modules\line-in
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN SpeechToText@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN SpeechToText@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! line-in@0.1.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the line-in@0.1.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.```
````

Comment: See my answer below. `node-gyp` found your python3 install and tried to use it, but it errors out on the python2 `print` usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node-gyp requires python2.7:

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

`python (v2.7 recommended, v3.x.x is not supported)`

There are some windows specific instructions that may help you:

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

Comment: Thanks `@davejagoda`. I am facing another issue `MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 S
DK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewh
ere.` I tried installing Visual Code that comes with C++ compiler. Should I need to to install Individual Components as well ?

Comment: It worked without any Individual Components. Thanks @devejagoda.